# Scala: Convert a string to string array with and without split given that all special characters except "(" an ")" are allowed

Tags: scala

I have an array

```
val a = "((x1,x2),(y1,y2),(z1,z2))"
```

I want to parse this into a scala array

```
val arr = Array(("x1","x2"),("y1","y2"),("z1","z2"))
```

Is there a way of directly doing this with an expr() equivalent ?
If not how would one do this using split

Note : x1 x2 x3 etc are strings and can contain special characters so key would be to use  () delimiters to parse data -

Code I munged from Dici and Bogdan Vakulenko

```
val x2 = a.getString(1).trim.split("[\()]").grouped(2).map(x=>x(0).trim).toArray

val x3 = x2.drop(1) // first grouping is always null dont know why

var jmap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]()

for (i<-x3)
{
 val index = i.lastIndexOf(",")
 val fv = i.slice(0,index)
 val lv = i.substring(index+1).trim
 jmap.put(fv,lv)
}
```

This is still suceptible to "," in the second string -

Comment: Is the second snippet an array of strings, or is `x1` (for example) a variable? Also, I think not using split is an unncessary constraint. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Spark has this useful feature for expr() which directly evaluates the expression - This is already in the format that we declare arrays in scala so splitting is needless if it can be avoided - Also I am assuming split will be long code -

Comment: I didn't downvote. If you're using this with Spark, please say it in the question. Also, I still don't get your second snippet. Is `x1` a variable or is it the string `"x1"` ?

Comment: I didnt add spark because this is not a dataset / frame purely a string not a part of any dataframe - And yes its a string not variable

Comment: But `expr` in Spark is a very different thing, it's just syntactic sugar for generating a SQL-like query. Here we're talking about pure Scala, `expr` will be useless. You **have** to parse this string, and the most sensible way to do it is to use `split`.

Comment: Yes thats why I did not rule out split in my question as well :) just was trying to find the easy way out  - probably using the substring function would help ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I focused too much on the title. I have proposed a solution based on regex because `split` is actually difficult to use here.

Comment: Why are you using a Java map? Scla also has a mutable hash map

Comment: Yeap could use that too -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think regex are the most convenient way to solve this.

```
val a = "((x1,x2),(y1,y2),(z1,z2))"
val regex = "(\\((\\w+),(\\w+)\\))".r
println(
  regex.findAllMatchIn(a)
       .map(matcher => (matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3)))
       .toList
)
```

Note that I made some assumptions about the format:

- no whitespaces in the string (the regex could easily be updated to fix this if needed)
- always tuples of two elements, never more
- empty string not valid as a tuple element
- only alphanumeric characters allowed (this also would be easy to fix)

Comment: Damn i need to master regex :/ its like a disability without it

Comment: It can be useful sometimes, just don't over-use it :D If you want Hackerrank has some regex problems to train you on. Also use tools such as this one while training: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I found that x1 and x2 may have special characters in them . How would we edit this code to hande that

Comment: What kind of special characters? What would be the input and desired output?

Comment: - hyphens  - , commas & ampersands - We cant get rid of them - I munged your code to get this - i dont know if it helps - i added some code in the question itself

Comment: ( , ) is the only special characters that wont be used -

Comment: If it's any character except parentheses or comma, use `[^(),]` instead of `\\w+`. It literally means "anything except those three characters".

Answer (score 1):

```
val a = "((x1,x2),(y1,y2),(z1,z2))"

a.replaceAll("[\\(\\) ]","")
 .split(",")
 .sliding(2)
 .map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))
 .toArray
```

Comment: Thanks this is elegant as well

Comment: How does one handle spaces and special characters for this is x1 ,x2,y1,y2 are strings with spaces and - ?

Comment: just add characters that you want to ignore to replaceAll. I've edited the answer and added space in there.

Comment: `"[\\(\\) ]"` - this is the place where to add characters to be replaced with empty string.

Comment: Note: you don't need to escape parentheses inside of the square brackets (whatever is inside of them is interpreted as a simple character)